# Can I solve asyncMap without using a count variable?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Is there a way to write the function below with out using a counter variable to know when the timeOuts are complete.

Can it be done using async / await ?

I have provided both the test call and the current working function below.

```
// write asyncMap below such that results array holds
// ['one', 'two', 'three']
// when the callback results function is run
// asyncMap has the prototype asyncMap(callbackArray, resultsCallbck)

asyncMap([
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('one');
      }, 200);
    },
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('two');
      }, 300);
    },
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('three');
      }, 100);
    }
  ],
  (results) => {
    console.log(results); // ['one', 'two', 'three]
  }
);


//
//
function asyncMap(tasks, callback) {
  const results = [];
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    const func = tasks[i];
    // await runFunc();
    function cb (val) {
      results[i] = val;
      count++;
      console.log(i, count);
      if (count === tasks.length) {
        callback(results);
      }
    }
    func(cb);
  }
};
```

Comment: you need to [promisify](https://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) node style callbacks to use async/await

Comment: My understanding is that promises are an in-between old style callbacks and await / async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier than you think.

All you need is [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Without changing the way you call `asyncMap`, you can do something like this:

```js
/* Nothing changes here */
asyncMap([
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('one');
      }, 200);
    },
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('two');
      }, 300);
    },
    (cb) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb('three');
      }, 100);
    }
  ],
  (results) => {
    console.log(results); // ['one', 'two', 'three]
  }
);

/* Reduced the whole function into only 3 lines */
function asyncMap(tasks, callback){
  tasks = tasks.map(cb => new Promise(cb))
  return Promise.all(tasks)
    .then(callback);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did not use await / async?

Comment: @jakobdennison Because it's simply not needed. If you absolutely need to use `async/await`, you can write it like `callback(await Promise.all(tasks))`, which is the same.

Comment: you eliminated not just the count variable but the loop index variable as well ... in fact all the logic in the callback to the callback function.  Can you update your code to replace `cb` with `task` and explain why I don't see the callback in task explicitly called anywhere in your code.  Fascinating answer by the way.

Comment: I see it is the function signature for new Promise ( func )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) handles that for you if you're using promises, but will return the results in the order supplied (not the order completed):

```
// 'setTimeout' as a promise
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const results = await Promise.all([
  wait(300).then(() => "one"),
  wait(200).then(() => "two"),
  wait(100).then(() => "three")
]);

console.log(results); // ['one', 'two', 'three']
```